# isolated DC-DC reverse output

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I'd like to use this isolated DC-DC converter:

https://power.murata.com/datasheet?/data/power/ncl/kdc_nmg.pdf

to feed a 7915 linear regulator. 
I'm wondering if it is possible to use that DC-DC converter (the variant with +24V output) to feed the 7915 by reversing the polarity of the DC-DC output (so - goes to VIN on the 7915 and + goes to ground).

would that work correctly?

ps. I know it would be better to just get a single DC-DC converter to obtain -15V, but I really need to go into the 7915.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The linked datasheet specifically states that this is suitable for creating a negative rail in a system where only positive rails exist.

Answer (score 0):

Since the converter is isolated you can used its positive output as ground. The circuit that you're envisioning will work, but note that the 9V drop will result in a lot of wasted power; you may need to use a TO-3 with a decent heatsink if you're pulling more than a few hundred mA.

Comment: actually this DC-DC converter can only provide 83mA max, so I guess heat on the 7915 is not a proble, right?

Comment: That's still 0.75W, which means a 30-45K increase above ambient with no heatsink. So not dangerous, but you don't want to touch it.